# Get title of page

Tags: 8

When I get the title on some pages, I get an empty title like *Home*. The code I am using in my subscriber is the following one.

```
class HistorySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('onResponse', 0);
    return $events;
  }

  public function onResponse($event) {
    $request = \Drupal::request();
    $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
    $title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route_match->getRouteObject());
  }
}
```

It is an issue? How I can fix it?

Comment: There is currently no clear API to do it, sadly. There used to be some issue to discuss that problem. The information is available in either hook_preprocess_page ... or temporarily in \Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlRenderer::prepare(), which sadly does not pass the title to any event. I guess we should fill an issue against drupal core to solve the situation ... as this is a clear usecase for people

Comment: @DanielWehner that is, let me create a issue in drupal.org

Comment: Could you please post the link to the issue you've filed on drupal.org?

Comment: @anavarre this is the issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2399615, but was closed because it is a duplicated of https://www.drupal.org/node/2264043

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be used to change page title.

```
// Alter page title.
$request = \Drupal::request();
if ($route = $request->attributes->get(\Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT)) {
  $route->setDefault('_title', 'Kontakt');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
  $request = \Drupal::request();
  $title=t('Home');
  if ($route = $request->attributes->get(\Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT) && !drupal_is_front_page()) {
    $title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route);
  }

?>
```

this code return null in front page, then you should try to check if [drupal_is_front_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/8) then show another title

Comment: That code does not work, on "Home" page $title is null

Comment: @RolandoPayánMosqueda if your problem is only in home, try detect front page then change it, I update my answer

Comment: Not only on "Home" occur this, on "admin/content" too and I am sure on others pages more.

Comment: @RolandoPayánMosqueda I think it is a drupal issue,drupal 8 is beta3,don't expect everything work correctly,specially new features and APIs :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside your function and You will get title of any page like term, node page...

```
public function getCurrentPageTitle() {
    $title = 'DEFAULT TITLE';
    $request = \Drupal::request();
    if ($route = $request->attributes->get(\Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT)) {
      // For Taxonomy Term
      if (!empty($request->attributes->get('taxonomy_term'))) {
        $title = $request->attributes->get('taxonomy_term')->get('title')->value;
      }
      // For Node
      else {
        $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
        if (!empty($node) && 'CONTENT_TYPE' === $node->bundle()) {
          $title = "CONTENT_TYPE_SPECIFIC_TITLE_SET";
          //$title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route);
        }
        else {
          $title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route);
        }
      }
    }
    return $title;
}
```